# org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: Connection timed out

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://106.51.38.64:9999/SumadhuraGateway/employeeservice/thirdParty/getEmployeeOfMultiplePortal.spring":Connection timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)

By Using RestTemplate called client API, i am facing above problem.
This exception occurring only in remote. Local server its working fine.

Comment: *This exception occurring only in remote.Local server its working fine* - check that the process is actually running and is not impeded by a firewall.  Also check the remote logs.

Answer (score 1):

first try this cmd in the remote server that didn't work fine
 ***ping 106.51.38.64***
this cmd shows if your host can reach target server "106.51.38.64";if this cmd shows the result like 'time out',so your host can not route to the host "106.51.38.64",but if ths cmd show like"0% packet lost",then excute this cmd:
***telnet 106.51.38.64 9999***
to make sure the firewall isn't the problem;

if telnet cmd  shows like "connect";
then you can try this cmd:
 ***curl -vvvvv -X POST 'http://106.51.38.64:9999/SumadhuraGateway/employeeservice/thirdParty/getEmploye**'*

to see where is the broke